# How can I center a table after having reduced it?

Tags: tables, beamer

I'm using ([Metropolis Theme like a Beamer](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/metropolis-beamer-theme/qzyvdhrntfmr#.WV0T3IgrLIU)) and I make a simple table and something big is shown, then I looked how to reduce it and I used:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} 
....
\end{minipage}}
\end{table}
```

and works fine, but the table isn't center position, always move more right side. I try to include all table using `\centering \begin{center} and \begin{flushleft}`, but it doesn't move.

Here my Table:

```
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{table}[H]
 \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{l| l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Parameters} & \textbf{Description of values}  \\
\toprule
$ Prohibited\_times $ & Timeslots prohibited for the event. \\
$ Prohibited\_rooms $ & Rooms prohibited for the event. \\
$ Prohibited\_events\_clash $ & Events you can not clash. \\
$ Count\_students $ & Number of students associated to the event. \\
$ Predecessor $ & Events predecessor to the event. \\
$ Successor $ & Event successor to the events. \\
$ Features $ & Characteristics of the event. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}}
\end{table}
\end{flushleft} 
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Any ideas?
regards

Comment: Avoid scaling tables via resizing the surrounding box. Use a smaller font and also use `\textunderscore` if you don't have any `\texttt` around the text instead of abusing math mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to include `\centering` after `\begin{table}[h]`?

Also, you can remove the `minipage` environment.

The example below worked just fine for me:

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.7\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Parameters} & \textbf{Description of values}  \\
\toprule
$ Prohibited\_times $ & Timeslots prohibited for the event. \\
$ Prohibited\_rooms $ & Rooms prohibited for the event. \\
$ Prohibited\_events\_clash $ & Events you can not clash. \\
$ Count\_students $ & Number of students associated to the event. \\
$ Predecessor $ & Events predecessor to the event. \\
$ Successor $ & Event successor to the events. \\
$ Features $ & Characteristics of the event. \\
\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried it but it continues the same way.

Comment: Can you add a minimum working example with your beamer settings? I used \centering and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with adjustbox and it worked. regards.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{l| l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Parameters} & \textbf{Description of values}  \\
\toprule
$ Prohibited\_times $ & Timeslots prohibited for the event. \\
$ Prohibited\_rooms $ & Rooms prohibited for the event. \\
$ Prohibited\_events\_clash $ & Events you can not clash. \\
$ Count\_students $ & Number of students associated to the event. \\
$ Predecessor $ & Events predecessor to the event. \\
$ Successor $ & Event successor to the events. \\
$ Features $ & Characteristics of the event. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
```